# Should initialization logic (say for numerous singletons) be in OnCreate or OnResume?

Tags: android

Say I have singletons with inilizations mehods for a generic LocationController, BatteryController, AppSateController,etc...

Should these be in onResume as opposed to OnCreate since OnCreate gets called on every rotate, every time it changes to foregroud, etc...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My recommendation is generally to implement singletons like you normally would directly.  Ignore Android, and just do the normal kind of thing like this:

```
class Singleton {
    static Singleton sInstance;

    static Singleton getInstance() {
        // NOTE, not thread safe!  Use a lock if
        // this will be called from outside the main thread.
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new Singleton();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Now call Singleton.getInstance() at the point you need it.  Your singleton will be instantiated at that point, and continue to be re-used for as long as your process exists.  This is a good approach because it allows your singletons to be lazily allocated (only as they are needed), rather than doing a bunch of up-front work for things you may not need right away which causes your launch (and thus responsiveness to the user) to suffer.  It also helps keep your code cleaner,  everything about your singleton and its management is located in its own place, and doesn't depend on some global place in your app being run to initialize it.

Also if you need a Context in your singleton:

```
class Singleton {
    private final Context mContext;

    static Singleton sInstance;

    static Singleton getInstance(Context context) {
        // NOTE, not thread safe!  Use a lock if
        // this will be called from outside the main thread.
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new Singleton(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private Singleton(Context context) {
        // Be sure to use the application context, since this
        // object will remain around for the lifetime of the
        // application process.
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against using singleton. I don't understand why would you `"really regret having introduced Application"`. You can write bad code both ways and with singleton is it much easier. Code using singletons is not easily testable. Also singleton can be accessed from anywhere, which sometimes leads to uses like `Singleton.getInstance(null)`, becase developer is "sure" it was already initialized by the first `Activity`. On the other hand `Application` subclass creates structure, which cannot be as easily broken. You access model through it and initilize it lazily if it is not there.

Comment: @hackbod does the bill pugh *Initialization On Demand Holder Idiom* singleton help or is it not relevant to android? described in wikipedia `public class Singleton {
 // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
 private Singleton() { }
 
 /**
 * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance() 
 * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
 */
 private static class SingletonHolder { 
  private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
 }
 
 public static Singleton getInstance() {
  return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

If You need initialize singletons (I assume application-level singletons), then appropriate way might be to extend [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and provide needed initialization in its [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) method. However, if initialization is heavy it might be a good idea to place it in separate thread, which get started from Application class.

Comment: I really strongly discourage the use of Application for this.  See my answer to the question for how I recommend doing it.  I actually really regret having introduced Application, it is this honey trap that seduces you into putting a huge swath of initialization code in one place that is really not needed and has negative consequences of slowing down the launch of apps and introducing unneeded dependencies between separate parts of the app.

Comment: With usual singleton implementation, will be these classes like 'detached' from the application itself? Do You think, having single reference to some object in Application and providing access method (with lazy initialization in there) is a bad idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by detached...  I updated my answer to show how you should write it if you need a context.  Either implementation will result in the same lifetime of the singleton after it is created (as long as the process is around).