# Should all initialization be in onResume() instead of onCreate()?

Tags: android

Given that only onResume() is guaranteed to run and state is lost after onPause().
Should all initialization be in onResume() instead of onCreate()?

For example,

```
myDbHelper = new MyDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

It was in onCreate(). Should I move it to onResume()?
I have a listAdapter. Should it be created in onResume()?

For singletons, yes, they would be implemented differently [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048902/should-initialization-logic-say-for-numerous-singletons-be-in-oncreate-or-onre) but what about other variables?

[android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm working on something related to your topic. I strongly recommand you to reuse all your variables into onResume(). Becouse you can just finish() your Activity B and for that the only methode that is call in Activity A is onResume(). Also use null pattern object to avoid null pointer exception for your variables.

Comment: what is 'null pattern object'? what is 'reuse all your variables into onResume()'?

Comment: Just simple pattern to avoid nullPointerException if(variable==null){ //do something here}

Answer (score 1):

Not always - onResume() gets triggered when the activity temporarily lost focus (like some pop up event) when the onPause() event was triggered and then you again gain focus (thereby triggering an onResume()). In this case, if you had initialized variables in onResume() they would all be re-initialized at this point and you would lose prior values.

The best example where I can think of where you do stuff in onResume() is when you set up a BroadcastReceiver - you don't want the receiver to trigger something when an alert has come to the foreground (you get the general idea).

Comment: I dont understand your last sentence - can you please clarify? If the receiver is registered, it will not be lost when the app is paused.

Comment: Like I said - it's an example. Imagine a scenario where when a particular action is broadcast, your application is expected to respond by kick starting a new event. Now you have a sudden popup coming up - most likely an emergency event. Now onPause() has been triggered but if the receiver is not de-registered here, it will kick off the new event potentially killing off the alert about the emergency event that you were expected to respond to. onPause() occurs when something else has suddenly come to the foreground (or something needs updates from the user often).

Comment: At this time, you don't want to kill off this event correct? I hope that made sense. Also if you are interested you might want to see the coding examples in the Android book by Commonsware where they follow this pattern. While they have not explicitly mentioned this, I found out while playing around with AlertDialogs that they get killed if a event was triggered by the Receiver. It's just a tip. Depending on your need, you can implement it any way you like.